# GTA IV - Out of Commission - Helicopter bug

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-iv

I am on the last mission of GTA 4 - Out of Commission (PC) and cannot finish due to the bug with getting on the helicopter.
I have read some terrible hacks to get it to work e.g. use Fraps, but that doesn't even seem to work in all cases. 
Is there a definitive fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if they will ever fix this, but here's a list o things you can try, worked for me:

1. used a wired keyboard;
2. remapped the jump key;
3. fps between 26 and 30.

Answer (score 1):

Still not fixed in 2020(Complete Edition). I've tried several fixes, but what helped me is to turn on VSync in graphics settings:
[image]