# GTA IV on Xbox 360 - Out of Commission - Helicopter bug

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-iv

I've hit on an Xbox 360 the same bug described in [GTA IV - Out of Commission - Helicopter bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25888/gta-iv-out-of-commission-helicopter-bug):
I am on the last mission of GTA 4 -- Out of Commission -- and cannot finish due to the bug with getting on the helicopter. The pop-up instructs me to `repeatedly hit A`, however `A` is mapped to "run" (and NOT to "jump/climb"). So it never works.

The solutions proposed in the linked Question do not seem to apply to the Xbox platform:

- I cannot use a wired keyboard
- I couldn't find a way to remap the jump key
- I couldn't find a way to set the fps

So how can I work around this bug on an Xbox 360 so as to complete the said mission?

Comment: What happens if you repeatedly hit the button that *is* mapped to jump/climb?

Comment: Tried that, too. Worse than hitting repeatedly `A`. With  `A` it always looks like something is happening, but it never really succeeds. With `X` absolutely nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very easy to work around this. You simply need to press your joystick `up` (as if you were moving forward) *and* repeatedly hit `A`. Then you get on the helicopter in no time.